# 5 Top selling brands and top selling products from them

Tags: mysql

I have these tables:

**Product_variants as PV**

```
CREATE TABLE `product_variants` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Products as P**

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `brand_id` int(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Order_items as OI**

```
CREATE TABLE `order_items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `order_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `product_variant_id` int(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Also orders and brands, which I assume are not needed for this example.

I would like obtain 15 rows where there will be 5 best-selling brands and three variants of them, sorted by marketability of brands and variants.

**Expected**

```
product_variant_id    brand_id   number_brands_sold   number_variant_sold
1                     1          100                  50
2                     1          100                  30
3                     1          100                  10
4                     2          90                   40                      
5                     2          90                   25
6                     2          90                   10
7                     3          80                   45
8                     3          80                   20
9                     3          80                   5
10                    4          60                   25
11                    4          60                   20
12                    4          60                   8
13                    5          40                   10
14                    5          40                   9
15                    5          40                   8
```

I can get variants based on variants sold, but I can't figure out how to incorporate brand sales into the query. Can it be that simple at all?

```
SELECT `pv`.`id` AS `product_variant_id`, `p`.`brand_id`, COUNT(DISTINCT `oi`.`order_id`) AS `number_variant_sold` 
FROM `product_variants` as pv
LEFT JOIN `products` AS `p` ON p.id = pv.product_id
LEFT JOIN `order_items` AS `oi` ON oi.product_variant_id = pv.id
GROUP BY `pv`.`id` 
ORDER BY `number_variant_sold` DESC 
LIMIT 15
```

This query only returns 1 in number_brand_sold and does not return correct results without DISTINCT. Additionally, it will always sort by number_brand_sold first and then number_variant_sold. I would need it to work according to the "Expected" table.

```
SELECT `pv`.`id` AS `product_variant_id`, `p`.`brand_id`, COUNT(`p`.`brand_id`) AS `number_brand_sold`, COUNT(DISTINCT `oi`.`order_id`) AS `number_variant_sold` 
FROM `product_variants` as pv
LEFT JOIN `products` AS `p` ON p.id = pv.product_id
LEFT JOIN `order_items` AS `oi` ON oi.product_variant_id = pv.id
GROUP BY `pv`.`id` 
ORDER BY `number_variant_sold` DESC 
LIMIT 15
```

**EDIT:**

I tried ask Chat GPT, but I did not get satisfactory answer. It seems that in mysql 5 it cannot be solved with one query. I couldn't find a solution even by splitting it into 2 queries.

Comment: Join. Group and count. Enumerate brands and products in brands. Select needed data.

Comment: Can you give an example in the answer? Classic join cannot be used.

Comment: TBH today I would probably write two simple queries and run the second one five times (once per brand).

Comment: Do you _really_ need two ids for the same thing??  Get rid of `id` and promote the other column to be `PRIMARY KEY`.

Answer (score 3):

This will be something near this:

```
WITH
cte1 AS (  -- count the amounts per variant and per brand
  SELECT brand_id, 
         product_variant_id, 
         COUNT(product_variant_id) number_variant_sold,
         SUM(COUNT(product_variant_id)) OVER (PARTITION BY brand_id) number_brands_sold
  FROM products
  JOIN product_variants ON products.id = product_variants.product_id
  JOIN order_items ON product_variants.id = order_items.product_variant_id
  GROUP BY brand_id, product_variant_id
  ),
cte2 AS (  -- enumerate brands and variants within brand
  SELECT brand_id, 
         product_variant_id, 
         number_variant_sold,
         number_brands_sold,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY number_brands_sold DESC) rn_within_brands,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY brand_id
                            ORDER BY number_variant_sold DESC) rn_variant_within_brand
  FROM cte1
)
SELECT brand_id, 
       product_variant_id, 
       number_variant_sold,
       number_brands_sold
FROM cte2
WHERE rn_within_brands <= 5
  AND rn_variant_within_brand <= 3
ORDER BY number_brands_sold DESC,
         number_variant_sold DESC
```

Possible disadvantage - if 5th and 6th brands have the same total amount then both of them they will be returned.

One more disadvantage - if 3rd and 4th variants have the same amount then one unpredictable of them will be returned.

But there is no additional criteria in any of the above cases.

Comment: Ok, WITH seems to be a deprecated construct. Could you rewrite it without it, please?

Comment: @tomasr *WITH seems to be a deprecated construct* O_O

Comment: And is it possible to write it using temporary or derived tables?

Comment: @tomasr Yes, this is possible (does your server version is 5.x?), but the query will be too complex.. Create iterative stored procedure with cursor(s) and temptable.

Comment: Yes mysql server is version 5.x.
I would expect that when it replaces some function, that it can be used in other ways (needs to be simpler). I also read that inline views can be used, which I honestly don't know at all. I would like to avoid procedures.
Can you write a query where there will be no WITH, i.e. using temporary or delivered tables or inline views?

Answer (score 0):

You could do with some temporary tables.

A script like this should collate the counts, store the top 5 brands and run 2 queries.

```
-- build counts of product variants
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE PV_Order_Counts
select product_variant_id, count(id) PV_Count from Order_Items
GROUP BY product_varient_id

-- sum up orders by brand
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Prod_Order_Counts
SELECT Product_Id, SUM(PV_Order_Counts.PV_Count) Prod_Count from Product_variants, @PV_Order_Counts
WHERE PV_Order_Counts.product_variant_id = Product_vatiants.id
GROUP BY Product_id
ORDER BY Prod_Count
LIMIT 5

-- retrieve top 5 product brands
SELECT Product_id, Brand_Id, Prod_Count from Prod_Order_Counts
INNER JOIN Products on Prod_Order_Counts.Product_id=Products.id

-- retrieve sales of product variants in top 5
SELECT Products.id Product_Id, Product_Variants.id Product_Variant_Id, Products.Brand_Id, PV_Count from PV_Order_Counts
INNER JOIN Product_Variants on PV_Order_Counts.product_variant_id = Product_Variants.id
INNER JOIN Products on Product_Variants.Product_id=Products.id
WHERE Products.id in (
  SELECT Product_id from @Prod_Order_Counts -- This temporary table is expected to have only 5 rows.
  )
ORDER BY Product_Id, Product_Variant_Id

-- Once finished, drop the tables.
DROP TABLE PV_Order_Counts
DROP TABLE Prod_Order_Counts
```

At this point, it might be simpler to stop and to use the two query outputs separately. You could however, rewrite the last query:

```
SELECT Products.id Product_Id, Product_Variants.id Product_Variant_Id, Products.Brand_Id, Prod_Count, PV_Count from PV_Order_Counts
INNER JOIN Product_Variants on PV_Order_Counts.product_variant_id = Product_Variants.id
INNER JOIN Products on Product_Variants.Product_id=Products.id
INNER JOIN @Prod_Order_Counts ON Products.id = Prod_Order_Counts.Product_id -- This temporary table is expected to have only 5 rows.
Order BY Prod_Count DESC, PV_Count DESC
```

This still does not impose your 3 variant limit.

For that, you could create a third temporary table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Top_Prod_Output (
   'Product_Id' int(11) UNSIGNED,
   'Product_Variant_Id' int(11) UNSIGNED,
   'Brand_Id' int(11) UNSIGNED,
   'Prod_Count'  int(11) UNSIGNED,
   'PV_Count'  int(11) UNSIGNED)
```

Then iterate through results:

```
DECLARE @Product_Id, @Prod_Count INT;
DECLARE curP CURSOR FOR SELECT Product_Id from Prod_Order_Counts;
OPEN curP;

LOOP
  FETCH curP INTO @Product_Id, @Prod_Count
  
  INSERT INTO Top_Product_Output
  SELECT @Product_Id, Product_Variants.id, Products.Brand_Id, @Prod_Count, PV_Count from PV_Order_Counts
  INNER JOIN Product_Variants on PV_Order_Counts.product_variant_id = Product_Variants.id
  INNER JOIN Products on Product_Variants.Product_id=Products.id
  WHERE Products.id = @Product_Id
  LIMIT 3
  
END LOOP;

-- Extract the results
SELECT * from Top_Product_Output
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
WITH BrandSales AS (
    SELECT p.brand_id, COUNT(DISTINCT oi.order_id) AS   number_brand_sold
    FROM products AS p
    LEFT JOIN product_variants AS pv ON p.id =  pv.product_id
     LEFT JOIN order_items AS oi ON oi.product_variant_id = pv.id
     GROUP BY p.brand_id
    ORDER BY number_brand_sold DESC
     LIMIT 5
)

 SELECT pv.id AS product_variant_id, p.brand_id,
        COALESCE(bs.number_brand_sold, 0) AS number_brand_sold,
       COUNT(DISTINCT oi.order_id) AS number_variant_sold
FROM product_variants AS pv
 LEFT JOIN products AS p ON p.id = pv.product_id
 LEFT JOIN order_items AS oi ON oi.product_variant_id = pv. id
LEFT JOIN BrandSales AS bs ON p.brand_id = bs.brand_id
GROUP BY pv.id, p.brand_id
ORDER B Y COALESCE(bs.number_brand_sold, 0) DESC, number_variant_sold DESC
LIMIT 15;
```

Here, we first create a common table expression (CTE) called

> BrandSales

to calculate the number of products sold for each brand and limit the results to top 5 brands by sales. Then, we should join this CTE with the product variants and calculate the number of product variants sold for each brand. The result is ordered by the number of brands sold  and then by the number of variants sold.